# Using two different Nvidia cards in one PC

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, sli

I'm going to install GeForce 1660 and GeForce 710 on my PC. I want to use 710 card with VGA monitor and 1660 with another HDMI monitor. Also i'm going to render 3d graphics with 1660 while using weaker 710 for other tasks at the same time.

Is that set-up possible? Will it negatively affect performance of main video card (1660)? or no?

Comment: Any time we have added a Graphics card, we have had to turn off built-in Graphics. I do not think you can have two graphics card running smoothly at the same time

Answer (score 1):

People often run  multiple GPUs.  It will work perfectly fine. You can configure settings in the GeForce control panel for application specific settings of necessary.